# Stripe form change layout of form elements

Tags: reactjs

Ive just started using Stripe in a React app

I'm using the quick set up from the site

```
    "use client"
    import {Elements} from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
    import {StripeElementsOptions, loadStripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js';
    import CheckoutForm from './checkOutForm';

    // Make sure to call `loadStripe` outside of a component’s render to avoid
    // recreating the `Stripe` object on every render.
    const stripePromise = loadStripe('---');

    export default function App() {
      const options: StripeElementsOptions = {

        mode: 'payment',
        currency: 'usd',
        amount: 1099,

        appearance: {
          theme: 'stripe',
          variables: {
              colorPrimary: '#0570de',
              colorBackground: 'white',
              colorText: 'red',
              colorDanger: '#fffdfd',
              fontFamily: 'Ideal Sans, system-ui, sans-serif',
              spacingUnit: '2px',
              borderRadius: '4px'
          }
      }
      };

      return (
        <div className="form">
          <Elements stripe={stripePromise} options={options}>
            <CheckoutForm />
          </Elements>
        </div>
      );
    };
```

This gives me form like

[image]

But I would like the form to be like

[image]

I know I can change the appearance with the appearance object but how can I add the Name on card field and change the position of the other fields. Is that with appearance as well